# Error in thread/integer parsing in java graphics

Tags: java, text, input, integer, field

I have a text field:

```
txtsides = new JTextField(); //text field for number of sides
txtsides.setBounds(50, 10, 20, 30);
txtsides.setColumns(3);
Sides_label_panel.add(txtsides);
```

and I have to input the number of sides into that field by:

```
side = Integer.parseInt(txtsides.getText());;` //set number of sides
```

but I am having the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
```

No idea why. help please...

Comment: Well, you got an empty input. You need to validate what's in your `JTextField`.

Comment: it wasn´t able to parse the empty String, you should check if the text is not empty or if it´s a valid Number first.

Comment: You'll need to include where this code is being called      side = Integer.parseInt(txtsides.getText());;'   Is that in an eventlister for a button click? keypress event listener for the TextField?    ( by the way looks like you've got some extra characters on that line ).

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer.parseInt("some_string" );
```

This method tries to convert the string provided to it to an Integer instance. So it would fail if the input is not a number in string. For ex: "abc", "9p" etc. And that failure would be a NumberFormatException - an exception that comes up when formatting a string to number is not possible.

Check if you are passing in what you are expecting to be passed.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to parse an empty string as an int, which does not work. Which int should "" be parsed as? The `JTextField` needs to have a text that can be parsed.

```
txtsides.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        ansTxt = (JTextField) e.getSource();
        try {
            int aInt = Integer.parseInt(ansTxt.getText());
            //Do whatever you want with the int
        } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
            /*
             * handle the case where the textfield 
             * does not contain a number, e.g. show
             * a warning or change the background or 
             * whatever you see fit.
             */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `KeyListener` isn't good solution, better to use `DocumentFilter`.